# Can somebody help me with locators for ng-contents with links?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, automation, protractor

I am trying to click on a header in my application that directs me to another screen. However, I observe that the locators are not helping me here.
Also the following code does not work:

`element(by.xpath("//a[@routerlink='/opportunities/list']")).click();`

The css locator too generated by ChroPath does not work

`element(by.xpath("//a[@routerlink='/opportunities/list']")).click();`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWESC.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO , please add html code snip as part of question, so that community members can reproduce/edit the problem to help , aslo read this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If there are multiple `<a> tags` with routerlink as `'/opportunities/list'`, then it won't work. You will have to use `element.all(by.xpath("//a[@routerlink='/opportunities/list']")).get(0).click()`. If you want to click the first `<a> tag` which has routerlink as `'/opportunities/list'`. If you want to click the second `<a> tag`, then use `element.all(by.xpath("//a[@routerlink='/opportunities/list']")).get(1).click()` and so on.

Comment: @SaddamPojee - Great! This works too.But, would be more useful in case where I will have multiple links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Protractor [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api)? We also recommend not using [xpath](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide) because it causes your locator to be brittle and it is hard to debug. There are alternatives to xpath like linkText or just by css. In the two items below, I'll use async / await which your tests should be using since the control flow will be deprecated.

#### Option 1

Your html has text for your link so you want to use the [webdriver.By.linkText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.linkText)

`await element(by.linkText('opportunities')).click();`

#### Option 2

You can use css to match attributes and tags:

`await element(by.css('a[routerlink="/opportunities/list"])).click()`

Comment: Thanks! Option 2 worked out perfectly for me! Well, yes..Xpath makes it hard to debug.